# How to disable fatal error showing in java?

Tags: java, exception, xml-parsing

I would like to know if it is possible to disable the **[Fatal Error]:1:50: White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.** error in my java program.

Im using java built-in DOM parser api to parse an XML document. The xml document is deliberately incorrect because I want to learn how to handle exceptions related to xml parsing. I also want to say that when the xml document is correct, no exception occurs.

I have already tried with the following :

```
try {
    Document doc = documentBuilder.parse(xmlDocument)
} catch (Throwable t){
     System.out.println("An error occur when parsing");
}
```

The code inside the catch block is displayed correctly but the fatal error message is still showing.

If anyone has a solution, I would be delighted, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that by default the [error handler](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.xml/org/xml/sax/ErrorHandler.html) for the XML parser prints the errors to the output. You can install your own handler to capture or ignore the errors:

```
class NullErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    @Override
    public void fatalError(SAXParseException e) {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void error(SAXParseException e) {
        // do nothing
    }
    
    @Override
    public void warning(SAXParseException e) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

Use it as follows:

```
documentBuilder.setErrorHandler(new NullErrorHandler());
```

You could also have an error handler that, for example, stored the exceptions in lists in member variables, so you could access them and examine them after parsing the document.

Here's a fully worked-out example:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;

String xml = """
             <?xml version="1.0"?>
             <!DOCTYPE whatsupdoc PUBLIC
                 "http://example.com/bugs""http://example.com/bunny">
             """;

InputSource getXmlInput(String xml) {
    InputSource is = new InputSource();
    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
    return is;
}

var documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();

documentBuilder.parse(getXmlInput(xml));  // prints the error and throws
documentBuilder.setErrorHandler(new NullErrorHandler());
documentBuilder.parse(getXmlInput(xml));  // only throws, does not print
```